# Sort Data.Map by value and get all biggest values

Tags: haskell

I have Data.Map that looks like this:

```
fromList [("eso",1),("mes",1),("ome",2),("som",2)]
```

I need to get list of keys from this map where the values are biggest:

```
["ome","som"]
```

Here is my solution:

```
get_max_from_map m = map fst (filter is_biggest sorted)
    where sorted = List.sortBy (\(k1, v1) (k2, v2) -> v2 `compare` v1) $ Map.toList m
          max_v = snd $ head sorted
          is_biggest (key, value) = value == max_v
```

I convert map to list, sort them, get first value as maximum and filter list.

I am just wondering if there is more optimal and beautiful solution of this task ?

Thanks.

Comment: If there is no reason to have a fast lookup, you might want to consider using a heap instead of a map. With a heap, the biggest elements are always the topmost elements and are therefore easily accessible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't any simpler than what is in your original post, but it has the advantage of being a linear-time, one-pass solution (your version is O(*n* log *n*) since it sorts the list, and the other answers posted so far are two-pass solutions).

```
getMaxFromMap m = go [] Nothing (Map.toList m)
  where
    go ks _        []           = ks 
    go ks Nothing  ((k,v):rest) = go (k:ks) (Just v) rest
    go ks (Just u) ((k,v):rest)
        | v < u     = go ks     (Just u) rest
        | v > u     = go [k]    (Just v) rest
        | otherwise = go (k:ks) (Just v) rest
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this using functions from `Data.Map` in the `Maybe` monad.

**EDIT**: here's a working version that makes use of a [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) import.

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

getYourKeys :: Eq a => Map k a -> Maybe [k]
getYourKeys m = do
  maxValue <- maximumOf traverse m
  return . Map.keys . Map.filter (== maxValue) $ m
```

Comment: Err, this is actually incorrect and just happens to work on your particular use case.  `Map.maxView` works on keys, not values.  I'll fix / delete this in a minute or two. (update: fixed)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do 2 tasks - find maximum, filter

```
get_max_from_lst xs = map fst $ filter ((== m) . snd) xs
    where m = maximum $ map snd xs
```

This is for list.

If we have Map, then:

```
import Data.Map.Lazy as M

get_max_from_map xs = M.keys $ M.filter (== m) xs
    where m = maximum $ M.elems xs
```

Comment: I think you need to convert the argument to a list first.