# Determine binary tree level with most occurrences of an element in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, I'm trying to find the binary tree's level with the highest number of occurrences of an element, for example `Apple`.

Here are the specs:

```haskell
data Fruit = Peach | Apple
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
levelWithMaxApples :: BTree Fruit -> Int
```

I was able to make a function which, given a binary tree, it will count the occurrences of `Apple` in it. Nevertheless, I was cannot figure out how to find the level with most occurrences of `Apple`, any hint?

Here are some tests:

```
tree1 = Node Peach Empty Empty

tree2 = Node Peach 
          (Node Peach
            (Node Apple
              Empty
              Empty)
            (Node Peach
              (Node Peach
                Empty
                Empty)
              (Node Peach
                Empty
                Empty)))
          (Node Apple
            (Node Apple
              Empty
              (Node Peach
                Empty
                Empty))
            Empty)

> levelWithMaxApples tree1
Nothing

> levelWithMaxApples tree2
2
```

Here is my attempt (in this case the function's name should be `countApples`:

```haskell
levelWithMaxApples Empty = 0
levelWithMaxApples (Node Apple l r) = 1 + levelWithMaxApple l + levelWithMaxApple r
levelWithMaxApples (Node Peach l r) = levelWithMaxApple l +   levelWithMaxApple r
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you write b-tree, do you actually mean *binary* tree? A B-tree is a very important data structure too, but a rather different one.

Comment: @dfeuer I think it's quite clear from the examples that OP means binary tree. I'm going to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way.

1. Start with a helper function. This will simply build the raw list of nodes and count of `Apple` at that node. However, this is separately done for each node in each subtree i.e. list will be something like [(Root,1),(L1,1),(L2,0),(R1,1)]

   ```
   import qualified Data.Map as M (fromListWith,toList)
   import qualified Data.List as L (sortBy)

   countApples' :: BTree Fruit -> Int -> [(Int,Int)]
   countApples' Empty _ = []
   countApples' (Node Apple l r) n = (n,1) : (countApples' l (n+1)) ++ (countApples' r (n+1))
   countApples' (Node Peach l r) n = (n,0) : (countApples' l (n+1)) ++ (countApples' r (n+1))
   ```
2. Next, we create a Map with the contents from above step. During this step, we we will aggregate the values at each level of the tree. Then we convert back to a list and sort by the value part of the tuple in descending order. The level with maximum instances of apple will then be the first element in the tuple at the head of the list.

   ```
   levelWithMaxApples  :: BTree Fruit -> Int
   levelWithMaxApples  Empty = error "Empty tree"
   levelWithMaxApples  x = fst $ head $ L.sortBy (\(k1,v1) (k2,v2) -> compare v2 v1) $ M.toList $ M.fromListWith (+) $ countApples' x 0
   ```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SYQTA86601)

However, you should note that this may not be a very efficient solution, due to the conversion to and from Map in addition to sorting.

Note: The sorting part was largely based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723523/sort-data-map-by-value-and-get-all-biggest-values) answer.

**UPDATE:** Here's a way to do it entirely with Maps.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

countApples :: BTree Fruit -> Int -> M.Map Int Int
countApples Empty _ = M.empty
countApples (Node Apple l r) n = M.unionsWith (+) [(M.singleton n 1 ),(countApples l (n+1)),(countApples r (n+1))] 
countApples (Node Peach l r) n = M.unionsWith (+) [(M.singleton n 0 ),(countApples l (n+1)),(countApples r (n+1))]

levelWithMaxApples  :: BTree Fruit -> Int
levelWithMaxApples t = fst $ M.foldWithKey (\k v acc@(k',v') -> if v >= v' then (k,v) else acc) (-1,-1) $ countApples t 0
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/AKZJ91076)

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks! I'll try to make it a little bit more efficient :)

Comment: It looks great, I'm going to try it immediately! :)

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is [literate Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Literate_programming). You can save it with a `.lhs` extension and load it in GHCi.**

```
> import Data.Ord (comparing)
> import Data.List (maximumBy)

> data Fruit = Peach | Apple
> data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
```

Try breaking this up into smaller pieces. First, write a function that will produce a list of all the levels in a tree:

```
> levels :: BTree a -> [[a]]
> levels Empty = []
> levels (Node x l r) = [x] : combine (levels l) (levels r)
>   where combine [] ys = ys
>         combine xs [] = xs
>         combine (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x ++ y) : combine xs ys
```

(Note that the `combine` helper function here is just like `zipWith (++)`, but continues after the shortest input is exhausted).

Once you have that, it's pretty easy find the instances of `Apple` in your list (and would be easier still if you added `deriving Eq` to your `Fruit` definition):

```
> countEach :: (a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [Int]
> countEach pred = map (length . filter pred)

> countApples :: [[Fruit]] -> [Int]
> countApples = countEach isApple
>   where isApple Apple = True
>         isApple _ = False
```

Next you can simply label each item in the list with its index number, using `zip`, and then use `maximumBy` to select the one with the largest count:

```
> levelWithMaxApples :: BTree Fruit -> Int
> levelWithMaxApples t = let ls = levels t
>                            counts = countApples ls
>                            labeled = zip [0..] counts
>                        in fst . maximumBy (comparing snd) $ labeled
```

Comment: thank you for the hint! I tried your code and I get an error: `parse error on input ‘=’` in `levels (Node x l r) = [x] : combine (levels l) (levels r)`. Do you know why?